# My CPU is running at an abnormal temp?

Tags: cpu, temperature, gaming

Basically, I built my PC a few days ago. On idle my cpu temp usually runs at 27-30 degrees Celsius. When playing games (like resident evil 5) or any other game I've tried so far, it'll only get to 30-33. When I ran a stress test, my CPU got up to 60 Celsius (I didn't run it very long, probably would've gotten higher) the odd thing is, my CPU cooler (Corsair H100i V2) runs max 30-33 degrees Celsius, so I find it odd that my CPU can run cooler than it at times. And the fact it never really gets higher than 30-35 degrees when playing games on ultra. My CPU cooler only got to 35 degrees during stress test. Could someone please help ease my mind or tell me what's wrong? Thanks. I have the i7 6700k, and am running a gtx 1080 graphics card

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Your CPU is running too cool?!

Comment: I just found it a bit odd. Especially when I see so many people saying their CPU can get up to 70 degrees. And the fact that my CPU cooler can run hotter than the actual CPU.

Comment: @Elol - Those people reporting their CPUs are reaching 70 degrees are running on air, you are running on liquid, which will result in much cooler temperatures.  What precisely is abnormal about those temperatures considering your using a liquid cooler?

Answer (score -2):

Given the beast of a GFX card (along with a high end CPU) you are using (and possibly the age of the games) the CPU probably doesn't have to work that hard. As you've seen yourself when you work the CPU during a stress test the temperature rises as expected.

If you want to ease your mind, run some monitoring software while playing (such as HWMonitor, AIDA64, Windows built in Resource Monitor, even the Task Manager in Win10 may give you enough insight) to monitor/log your CPU usage and I'm guessing you'll find it isn't that high.